# how to highlight bottom li when user scroll div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Could you please tell me how how to highlight bottom li when user scrolling   in a div? I have one container `div`, in which there are four `divs`. In the footer I also have four `li` (first, second, third,fourth). I want to select the `li` (background become red)when the user scrolls the respectively div's.

Example

When the code runs, the first `li` should be selected it background become red because the first div is in the view port. If the user scrolls and moves to the second div, the second `li` should be selected. And so on.

I tried like that

https://jsbin.com/giwizufotu/edit?html,css,js,output

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  $(function(){
    $( "#container" ).scroll(function() {
      console.log('scrlling');
      if (elementInViewport2($('#first'))) {
        // The element is visible, do something
        console.log('first visible')
    } else {
         console.log('second visible')
    }
    });
  })

  function elementInViewport2(el) {
  var top = el.offsetTop;
  var left = el.offsetLeft;
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var height = el.offsetHeight;

  while(el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
    left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
    (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
    (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
  );
}

})()
```

I don't want to use plugin

Comment: Since all the `li`'s is bigger than viewport. the logic you have will not work properly. A better approach would be to check their top position relative to the viewport, and then decide how far from viewport top it should be to consider it in view

Comment: could you please share view in fiddle or jsbin

Answer (score 0):

https://jsbin.com/borohoheji/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Look at what i did i check if the element is visible with `.is(':visible')`

You can work from there and do exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
    (function(){
  'use strict';
  $(function(){
    $( "#container" ).scroll(function() {
      console.log('scrlling');
      if (elementInViewport($('#first'))) {
    // The element is visible, do something
        console.log('first visible')
    } else {
         console.log('second visible')
    }
    });
    $( "#container >div" ).hover(
      function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
      });
  })
```

Comment: The _$("#container >div")_ selects every div in _#container_
The _.hover_ limits it to  only when a div gets a mouseover and the _.css_ sets the color to a highlight.
Just change the CSS to what you want..

Answer (score 0):

First, do the following :

- give all the text divs a classname eg `'para'`, to make them more readily selectable as a collection.
- establish a `ul.fC li.active {...}` directive in your style sheet to give the desired visual effect.

Then :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
        var $container = $("#container"),
            $paras = $container.children(".para"), // the four text divs.
            $listElements = $(".footer ul.fC li"), // the four li elements in the footer.
            oldIndex = -1;
        $container.scroll(function() {
            var index = $paras.index($paras.filter(visibleY).eq(0)); // position of the first visible text div.
            if(index !== oldIndex) { // avoid unnecessary work
                $listElements.eq(oldIndex).removeClass('active'); // remove highlight
                $listElements.eq(index).addClass('active'); // add highlight
                oldIndex = index; // remember index for next event turn
            }
        }).trigger('scroll');
        function visibleY() {
            // based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/21627295/3478010
            var el = this; // because function is called as a .filter() callback.
            var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(), 
                top = rect.top, 
                height = rect.height, 
                el = el.parentNode;
            do {
                rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (top <= rect.bottom === false) return false;
                // Check if the element is out of view due to a container scrolling
                if ((top + height) <= rect.top) return false
                el = el.parentNode;
            } while (el != document.body);
            // Check its within the document viewport
            return top <= document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        };
    });
})();
```

As written above, the change of style will happen in response to paras exiting/entering the container's top edge.

The behaviour can be changed to respond to paras exiting/entering the container's bottom edge by replacing :

```
var index = $paras.index($paras.filter(visibleY).eq(0)); // position of the first visible para.
```

with :

```
var index = $paras.index($paras.filter(visibleY).last()); // position of the last visible para.
```

Choose whichever is more desirable.